# Укажите правильное объяснение постановки запятой или ее отсутствия

Tags: пунктуация

"Где-то далеко в стороне напряженно ( ) и трубно гудели пароходы".
1)   Простое предложение с однородными членами, перед союзом И запятая не нужна.
2)   Сложносочиненное предложение, перед союзом И запятая не нужна.
3)   Простое предложение с однородными членами, перед союзом И запятая  нужна.
4)   Сложносочиненное предложение, перед союзом И запятая  нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант - запятая не нужна.